Difficulty plotting spectrogram for EEG data in Python
I'm doing some task imitates some plots of Regulation of brain cognitive states through auditory, gustatory, and olfactory stimulation with wearable monitoring - but I have a problem when I was trying to plot a spectrogram of EEG in Python with the library scipy.
I'm trying to plot a spectrogram for EEG data recorded from a Muse headband dataset. Here are the steps I've followed based on the instructions provided:

Preprocessing: I applied a high-pass filter above 1 Hz and a low-pass filter below 50 Hz to the raw EEG signals using signal.butter. Then, I attempted to downsample the signals from 256 Hz to 128 Hz using signal.resample and signal.decimate, but I'm encountering a ValueError: "Length of values does not match length of index."

Plotting Spectrogram: I used signal.spectrogram to compute the spectrogram for channels TP9 and TP10. However, when plotting, only the axes are visible, and there's no EEG signal.


# Extract the desired channels (TP9 and TP10)

channels = ['TP9', 'TP10']  
eeg_data = eeg_df[channels]

# Convert the timestamps to time in seconds

sampling_rate = 256  # Sampling rate of the EEG data in Hz
time_seconds = eeg_df['timestamps'] / sampling_rate

# Preprocess the EEG signals

for channel in channels:
    # Apply high-pass filter above 1 Hz and low-pass filter below 50 Hz
    b, a = signal.butter(4, [1, 50], btype='bandpass', fs=sampling_rate)
    eeg_data[channel] = signal.filtfilt(b, a, eeg_data[channel])
    
    # Downsample the signal from 256 to 128 Hz

    new_length = len(eeg_data[channel]) // 2
    eeg_data[channel] = signal.resample(eeg_data[channel], new_length)

# Define the parameters for the spectrogram

window = 'hann'  # Windowing function

nperseg = 128    # Length of each segment

noverlap = 64    # Overlap between segments

nfft = 128       # Number of points for the FFT

# Compute the spectrogram for each channel

frequencies, times, spectrogram_TP9 = signal.spectrogram(eeg_data['TP9'], fs=sampling_rate / 2, window=window,nperseg=nperseg, noverlap=noverlap, nfft=nfft)
frequencies, times, spectrogram_TP10 = signal.spectrogram(eeg_data['TP10'], fs=sampling_rate / 2, window=window,nperseg=nperseg, noverlap=noverlap, nfft=nfft)

# Plot the spectrogram for TP9

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.pcolormesh(times, frequencies, 10 * np.log10(spectrogram_TP9), shading='gouraud', cmap='viridis')
plt.title('Spectrogram for TP9')
plt.xlabel('Time (seconds)')
plt.ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.colorbar(label='Power/Frequency (dB/Hz)')
plt.ylim(0, 30)  # Limit the y-axis to frequencies up to 30 Hz

# Plot the spectrogram for TP10

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.pcolormesh(times, frequencies, 10 * np.log10(spectrogram_TP10), shading='gouraud', cmap='viridis')
plt.title('Spectrogram for TP10')
plt.xlabel('Time (seconds)')
plt.ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.colorbar(label='Power/Frequency (dB/Hz)')
plt.ylim(0, 30)  # Limit the y-axis to frequencies up to 30 Hz

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

I suspect the issue might be related to mismatched lengths after downsampling or incorrect usage of the signal processing functions. Could someone please help me troubleshoot this issue and provide guidance on how to correctly plot the spectrogram for the EEG data?, I attached in images my error, and also my data set information and values.
Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
EEG figure desired:


Welcome to SO.  In general, mashing two questions together like this is frowned upon.  In this case, it means that for a full answer you need someone who knows scipy.signal and matplotlib, and makes the result less searchable and less clear for later readers.  I'd suggest splitting the matplotlib question off into another question.

Welcome to SO, picture are very poor medium to exchange textual data. Never post screenshot of code, error and data, copy paste and format instead. You cannot expect people to retype by hand your dataset from a picture. Also read how to write a [mcve] and [ask].

Alright I'm gonna delete the code image.

I've sought to create the desired plot using similar data. I started by visualising the original and filtered signals, before creating the spectrograms.
I think the error you were seeing was because you were assigning a downsampled signal to the original dataframe, which won't work as they are different lengths. To get round this, I assigned the downsampled data to a new dataframe eeg_downsampled.
Original and processed channels:

Spectrograms:


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from scipy import signal

#
# Load some test data and modify it to look more like the OP's data
#
eeg_df = pd.read_csv('../musedata_meditation.csv')
eeg_df = df.rename(columns={'RAW_TP9': 'TP9', 'RAW_TP10': 'TP10'})
eeg_df['sample_number'] = range(len(eeg_df))

# Sampling rate of the EEG data in Hz
sampling_rate = 256  

# Convert the sample index to time in seconds
# This means you need to divide the sample *number* by the sampling rate
eeg_df['time_seconds'] = eeg_df['sample_number'] / sampling_rate

# Extract the desired channels (TP9 and TP10)
keep_channels = ['TP9', 'TP10']
eeg_data = eeg_df[keep_channels + ['time_seconds']].copy()

#
# Preprocess the EEG signals
#

#Define the pre-preprocessing parameters
downsample_factor = 2
bp_order = 4
bp_passband = [1, 50]
downsample_factor = 2

eeg_downsampled = pd.DataFrame()
downsampled_length = len(eeg_data) // downsample_factor

for channel in keep_channels:
    filtered_name = channel + '_bp'
    # Apply high-pass filter above 1 Hz and low-pass filter below 50 Hz
    b, a = signal.butter(bp_order, bp_passband, btype='bandpass', fs=sampling_rate)
    eeg_data[filtered_name] = signal.filtfilt(b, a, eeg_data[channel])
    
    # Downsample the signal from 256 to 128 Hz
    # Put the shorter signals in a new dataframe "eeg_downsampled"
    eeg_downsampled[channel] = signal.resample(eeg_data[filtered_name], downsampled_length)
eeg_downsampled['time_seconds'] = np.arange(new_length) / (sampling_rate / downsample_factor)

#
# View the original and processed data
#
plot_height = 2
n_plots = 3
f, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=n_plots, ncols=1,
                      figsize=(11, plot_height * n_plots),
                      layout='constrained', sharex=True)

plot_slice = slice(0, 2500) #window of data to plot

#Original data
eeg_data[plot_slice].plot(
    y=keep_channels, x='time_seconds',
    ylabel='signal', xlabel='time (s)',
    linewidth=1, ax=axs[0],
    title=f'original data (samples {plot_slice.start} to {plot_slice.stop})'
)

#Filtered
eeg_data[plot_slice].plot(
    y=[chan + '_bp' for chan in keep_channels], x='time_seconds',
    ylabel='signal', xlabel='time (s)', legend=False,
    linewidth=1, ax=axs[1], title=f'bandpass {bp_passband}Hz'
)

#Downsampled
eeg_downsampled[plot_slice.start:plot_slice.stop//downsample_factor].plot(
    y=keep_channels, x='time_seconds',
    ylabel='signal', xlabel='time (s)', legend=False,
    linewidth=1, ax=axs[2], title=f'downsampled {downsample_factor}x'
)


# Define the parameters for the spectrogram
window = 'hann'  # Windowing function
nperseg = 128    # Length of each segment
noverlap = 64    # Overlap between segments
nfft = 128       # Number of points for the FFT

# Compute the spectrogram for each channel
spectrograms = {}
for channel in keep_channels:
    frequencies, times, spectrogram = signal.spectrogram(
        eeg_downsampled[channel],
        fs=sampling_rate / downsample_factor,
        window=window, nperseg=nperseg, noverlap=noverlap, nfft=nfft
    )
    spectrograms[channel] = spectrogram

# Plot the spectrograms
f, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(11, 5),
                      layout='constrained', sharex=True)
f.suptitle('Spectrograms')
vmin, vmax = -10, 30

for channel, ax in zip(keep_channels, axs):
    im = ax.pcolormesh(
        times, frequencies, 10 * np.log10(spectrograms[channel]),
        vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, #comment out for auto-range
        shading='nearest', cmap='viridis'
    )
    
    ax.set_ylim(0, 30)  # Limit the y-axis to frequencies up to 30 Hz
    ax.set_ylabel(('Left' if channel=='TP9' else 'Right') + f' ({channel})\nfrequency (Hz)')
    
    cbar = f.colorbar(im, aspect=8, pad=0.01, label='power/frequency (dB/Hz)')
    
ax.set_xlabel('time (s)')


Yes, this resolved my inquiry. Thanks, but in this part of the code:                                             signal.resample(eeg_data[filtered_name], downsampled_length) eeg_downsampled['time_seconds'] = np.arange(new_length) / (sampling_rate / downsample_factor)   I put the variable downsampled_length. It's okay?

My pleasure, glad it helped. Yes you're right, it should be downsampled_length.

Hello, bro I have a question about another plot, can i text you by email?

Yes I tried to clik in the mail symbol, but I think the link it doesn't work. I saw a gmail with the next format: name.stackoverflow@gmail.com, is that your email?.

This is the function I made for resampling my EEG signals as I had troubles with scipy resample.
def resample_filter(index, data, rate, target, interpolation='linear'):
    if target > rate:
        updata = []
        size = len(index)
        time = size // rate
        upindex = np.linspace(0, time, int(time * target))
        for i in range(len(data)):
            updata.append(scipy.interpolate.interp1d(np.linspace(0, time, size), data[i], kind=interpolation)(upindex))
        return upindex, updata, target
    factor = int(round(rate / target))
    return index[::1 if factor == 0 else factor], [data[i][::1 if factor == 0 else factor] for i in range(len(data))], rate // factor

It returns the new index, the new signal and the new sample rate.
Edit :
The scipy.resample version of resampler
def resample_filter(index, data, rate, target):
    time = len(index) // rate
    size = int(time * target)
    return np.linspace(0, time, size), [scipy.signal.resample(data[i], size) for i in range(len(data))], target

And the function i use for spectrogram with window in secs but it is the same as yours :
def stft_spectrogram(index, data, rate, window=1.0, type='blackman'):
    size = len(data)
    n = int(window * rate)
    f, t, sxx = signal.spectrogram(
        x=np.array(data), mode="complex", window=type, fs=rate, nperseg=n if n <= size else size)
    return np.linspace(index[0], index[-1], len(sxx[0])), f, sxx

It returns the time index, frequencies and stft complexes where np.abs(sxx) is frequency amplitude and np.angle(sxx) is the phase.
STFT Spectrogram is nice to see what's going on but you will face incertitude principle between time and frequency domains and you will have to play with window size to choose which side you prefer to see clearly losing data on the other side. To see if your filters are effective, you should start by plotting simple Power Spectral Density using signal.welch. It's like a mean of STFT. Here is an example :
STFT Spectrogram of EEG signal with 50Hz European AC peak from my work :(

Welch PSD of the signal

After scipy simple Notch filter :

After checking if your filters are effective, you can go with STFT spectrogram but you should also consider to plot some Morlet Wavelets or Hilbert Huang.

Wow really impressive code and plot bro. The last response it works but I'm gonna try with your code and I 'm gonna comment it.

No problem, nice if you made it worked
